# Parsing ARN from IAM Policy using Regex

Tags: regex, go

I have the following IAM Policy:

```
{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role>"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole","Condition":{"StringEquals":{"sts:ExternalId":"<account>"}}}]}
```

but the `"AWS"` portion can also be an array:

```
"AWS": [
      "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_1>",
      "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_2>"
]
```

What I need is a regex that can parse both structures and return the list of `arn:aws:sts` as a list of strings... how can I accomplish that using regex in Golang?
I tried to use `json.Unmarshal` but the object structure is different between `[]string` and `string`

Edit:

I have the following snippet:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`arn:aws:sts::[a-z0-9]*:assumed-role/custom_role/[a-z0-9]-*`)
result := re.FindAll([]byte(arn), 10)
for _, res := range result {
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}


>>> `arn:aws:sts::<account_id>:assumed-role/custom_role/`
```

Comment: Create 2 structures, parse with one, then with the other if first parsing fails.

Answer (score 2):

### Using JSON decoder

You can decode the `AWS` key directly into a custom type implementing the "json.Unmarshaler" interface and decode both inputs correctly.

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/V3JfFW9t07c)

```
type AWSRoles []string

func (r *AWSRoles) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err == nil {
        *r = append(*r, s)
        return nil
    }
    var ss []string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &ss); err == nil {
        *r = ss
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("cannot unmarshal neither to a string nor a slice of strings")
}

type AWSPolicy struct {
    Statement []struct {
        Principal struct {
            AWSRoles AWSRoles `json:"AWS"`
        } `json:"Principal"`
    } `json:"Statement"`
}
```

Here's a test for it

```
var testsAWSPolicyParsing = []struct {
    name      string
    input     []byte
    wantRoles []string
}{
    {
        name:      "unique role",
        input:     []byte(`{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role>"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole","Condition":{"StringEquals":{"sts:ExternalId":"<account>"}}}]}`),
        wantRoles: []string{"arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role>"},
    },
    {
        name:  "multiple roles",
        input: []byte(`{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Sid":"","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":["arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_1>","arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_2>"]},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole","Condition":{"StringEquals":{"sts:ExternalId":"<account>"}}}]}`),
        wantRoles: []string{
            "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_1>",
            "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/custom_role/<role_2>",
        },
    },
}

func TestParseAWSPolicy(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tc := range testsAWSPolicyParsing {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel()
            var p AWSPolicy
            err := json.Unmarshal(tc.input, &p)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal("unexpected error parsing AWSRoles policy", err)
            }
            if l := len(p.Statement); l != 1 {
                t.Fatalf("unexpected Statement length. want 1, got %d", l)
            }
            if got := p.Statement[0].Principal.AWSRoles; !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tc.wantRoles) {
                t.Fatalf("roles are not the same, got %v, want %v", got, tc.wantRoles)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Using a Regex

If you still want to use a regex, this one would parse it as long as:

- AWS account has only numbers [0-9]
- the custom role name has only alphanumeric characters and underscores

`var awsRolesRegex = regexp.MustCompile("arn:aws:sts::[a-z0-9]+:assumed-role/custom_role/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")`

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/dfnDbrY0YOW)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/9G5Cyc9Nwqd --- remove `t.Parallel` from your code and see it fails.

Comment: Alternatively, if you still want your tests run in parallel you can fix the race conditions like https://play.golang.org/p/S31yZlobE_g, see line 39

Comment: @zerkms you're right, I was all surprised that it worked, it was my bad all along. I've proposed a new solution